# Post Check Box in PhP

Tags: php, html, post

i got this annoying problem i can't figure out how to solve

After a quick research i found those links bellow, which i could partially make work

[verifying if checkbox is checked in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39478480/verifying-if-checkbox-is-checked-in-php)

[How to read if a checkbox is checked in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4554758/how-to-read-if-a-checkbox-is-checked-in-php)

This is my html:

```html
<form method="post">

<!-- CHECK BOX TIPO DE PRODUTO (INTEIRO/PEDAÇO) !-->
<input type="checkbox" name="stipo" id="stipo" value="1" onchange="document.getElementById('tipo').disabled = !this.checked;">Tipo         
<select name="tipo" id="tipo" disabled="false">
 <option value="Inteiro">Inteiro</option>
 <option value="Pedaço">Pedaço</option>
</select><br>

<input type="submit" href="/consulta/consulta_produto.php" class="loader" value="Consultar">

</form>
```

and this is my php:

```html
if ($_POST['stipo'] == 1){
echo "123";
} else {
echo "456";
}
```

Because at the Html code im using form like this:

```html
<form method="post">
</form>
```

and making the post with a submit button like that:

```html
<input type="submit" href="/consulta/consulta_produto.php" class="loader" value="Consultar">
```

It doesn't work due to the Href at the submit button.

However, if i do the Html code like this:

```html
<form action="/consulta/consulta_produto.php" method="post">

<input type="submit" class="loader" value="Consultar">

</form>
```

It will work. But, the problem of the form above is that my script stop working. I Cant use the method above because i need Href into the submit button, because when i submit the form, im loading the next page inside a Div

Just in case it helps, this is my Javascript and why i need the Href

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('.loader').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // stop the link loading the URL in href
        $('#content').load($(this).attr('href'));
    }); 
});
</script>
```

Anyone got some idea on how to make the POST method works with href instead of action on the form?

Comment: If you load the next page into a div, how is the form submitted? Sounds like what you need is ajax.

Comment: You can make the POST method work with an HREF using AJAX, instead of the form action.

Comment: Use `$(".loader").parent("form").submit` instead of `$(".loader").click`

Comment: well, i tought it would submit like that, but seems like i was wrong... maybe i have to try with ajax itself

Comment: Vivick, it seems like to be posting now, but the page doesnt load after that, i dont know if i messed up the code, could you please check if is that right? i named the form with "teste" and then changed the script to the following ------>  $(function() {
    $('.loader').parent("teste").submit {
        event.preventDefault(); // stop the link loading the URL in href
        $('#content').load($(this).attr('href'));
    }); 
});